# POST route indicating 404 error (EXPRESS)

Tags: node.js, express, router

Getting a 404 error on my POST route, here is what I have done in my auth.js (routes) file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const connection = require('../../helpers/db.js'); 

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
 }));

 //create a new user


  router.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    const insert = `INSERT INTO users ( email, password, name, lastname) values ('${req.body.email}', '${req.body.password}','${req.body.name}', '${req.body.lastname}' )`
    connection.query(insert, function (err, result) {
          if(err) {
             console.log('mysql error', error);
             res.status(500);
             res.send(error);
          } else {                  
           console.log('a new user was added!');
           res.send('Congrats, new user!');
         }
       })
     });


module.exports = router;
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const app = express();
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth/auth");



// Configuring the app

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.use("/signup", authRouter); 

//starting node server

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Listening on port " + server.address().port);
  });
```

If I change my route into a GET, it works fine, but as soon as I do a POST route it would keep telling me on postman there is a 404 error, been trying many things but im now stuck! Im a beginner here :)

Comment: your `signup` is available at path `/signup/signup`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried that already but it still doesnt work :-(

Comment: try removing both body-parser on router `router.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: no luck on that one either

Comment: it says: POST /signup 404 42.323 ms - 146

Answer (score 1):

I think you added a prefix to your route so the route is /signup/signup

Try to change this

```js
app.use("/signup", authRouter);
```

To this

```js
app.use(authRouter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though it still isn't working :(